# regexp with various combinations

Tags: c#, regex

Here is the pattern I am looking for **[stringData1|stringData2|OnlyNumericData1]**. The max size limit for **stringData1 is 10** and for **stringData2 is 50**. **At least one characters should be there in stringData1, stringData2 and OnlyNumericData1**.

**Case #1:** ("Here is the test subject line [testData1|CS-SPL-GD-2014-01254|678] and [[test-1213-778]"); // Returns: [testData1|CS-SPL-GD-2014-01254|678]

**Case #2:**"Here is the test subject line [testData1|1tes2345|678] and [resrtest-1213667-77448]"); // Returns: [testData1|1tes2345|678]

**Case #3**:("Here is the test subject line [test Data1|-12|iiiii|345-678] and [test|124413tryrtytry|77218]");// Returns:  [test|124413tryrtytry|77218]

**Case #4**:("Here is the test subject line [Hello Test|1w2345|678] and [Hellotest|122 2213|72278]");// Returns: Nothing to return. Because of blank space in the data

**Case #5**:("Here is the test subject line [33|1d-d-dff=gg2345|test] and [teddddst|1|21433}|7788888]");// Returns: Returns [33|1d-d-dff=gg2345|test] the first occurrence of pattern matching

What I have tried so far.

```
        var result = Regex.Match(subjectLine, @"\[\w{1,10}|\w{1,50}|[\d]+\]");
        if (result.Success)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
```

Looking for C# regular expressions for this criteria.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your regex:

1. You have to escape the pipe character `|`
2. `\w` does not match `-` or `=`. You probably want to use `\S`.

Result:

```
\[\S{1,10}\|\S{1,50}\|\d+\]
```